# How to prove that "image measure" $\mu_f$ is indeed a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a measure space $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and a measurable space $(Y,\mathcal D)$. Let $f : X → Y$ be a
function such that $f^{−1}
(D) \in\mathcal A$ for all $D \in\mathcal D$. Define a function $\mu_f : D → [0, \infty]$ by $$\mu_f(D)=\mu(f^{-1}(D))$$
We call $\mu_f$ the image measure of $f$

I need to do the following:

1. Show that $\mu_f$ is indeed a measure on $(Y,\mathcal D)$.
2. Given that $g:Y \to \mathbb{C}$ is a $\mathcal D$-measurable function show that $g \circ f$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: The proof of 1. is easy. What are your problems ?

Comment: I don't see what I have to show. It says $\mu_f$ is a mapping from $\mathcal D$ to $[0,\infty]$, and I thought all elements of $\mathcal D$ are by definition $\mathcal D$-measurable. And since the domain of  $\mathcal D$ is Y, then obviously $\mu_f$ is a measure on $(Y,\mathcal D)$

Comment: Not every function $\mathcal D\to[0,\infty]$ is a measure. It must have some defining properties. Secondly $f\circ g$ must change into $g\circ f$.

Comment: Yeah, these conditions being $0 \leq \mu_f for all A \in \mathcal A$ and the one you wrote with additivity?

Comment: Just see the link I provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
Just start by showing that $\mu_f$ is a [measure by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition).

Observe for instance that - if $D_1,D_2,\dots\in\mathcal D$ and are disjoint - then $f^{-1}(D_1),f^{-1}(D_2),\dots\in\mathcal A$ and are disjoint as well.

Secondly it can be shown that $f^{-1}(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}D_i)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(D_i)$

This opens the door to prove that: $$\mu_f(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_f(D_i)$$

I leave that up to you.

---

2)

If $B\subseteq\mathbb C$ is measurable then $g^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal D$ hence $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(B))\in\mathcal A$.

Now realize that $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(B))=(g\circ f)^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much again! You're awesome